# Microsoft Speech Platform: recognize word repetitions

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, grammar, microsoft-speech-platform

I use Microsoft Speech Platform to recognize speech at output it on screen. But, i have problem: for example, i have grammar (constructs by GrammarBuilder and Choices -  "red","green","black")

When i say- "red green black"- i can get only "red", maybe "red green" , but not "red green black".

Some code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");

// Create a new SpeechRecognitionEngine instance.
_sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU"));

_sre.SpeechHypothesized += _sre_SpeechHypothesized;
_sre.SpeechDetected += _sre_SpeechDetected;
//_sre.SetInputToWaveFile(@"c:\Test\Wavs\Wavs-converted\file.wav");
_sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

public void LoadGrammarIntoEngine(IEnumerable<String> textColl)
{
    Choices choices = new Choices();
    GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
    gb.Culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");


    if (choices != null && textColl != null)
    {
        choices.Add(textColl.ToArray());
        gb.Append(choices);
    }

}
public void Recognize() {
   if (_sre != null && _sre.Grammars.Count != 0) {                   
       _sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);                    
   }
}
```

So, how to fix this problem? Should i make SGRS-grammar with rules?
The grammar file is txt file with words like that:

Dictionary.txt

```
green
black
yellow
red
some other words
```

Comment: Add to your dictionary also `red green black`.

Comment: It is bad decision: i think that user can say : i like green\black , but i set dictionary like that:
I
like
green
black
etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Append method with repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms576577(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
 gb.Append(choices, 1, 10);
```

Comment: thanks or the answer. I'm having a problem when I have like a dictionary of 30+ words and set gb.Append(choices,1,100); 

My phrases generally has 20~40 words, but if the audio has 20 words and I set anything greater than 20 it does not recognize anything. Do you know why? I'm doing Sync Recognition.

Comment: You could add unconstrained loop too

Comment: Nikolay can you give me an example on how to do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure about GrammarBuilder, looks like it's not really possible. But it should be possible if you load SRGS grammar, there repeat value could be "1-" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362835(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks Nikolay! It's working using a Grammar XML with "1-"! awesome my friend!