# SAPI 5.4: Improving Continous Command Recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi

I can't seem to find a topic that matched my question. Speech recognition isn't my forte, so forgive my ignorance in not knowing the ins and outs of speech recognition.

I have a simulator that uses a grammar command file quite well. If I say a command, it gets recognized with great accuracy. My problem is that the recognizer doesn't handle stringing/saying multiple commands in quick succession. Since my simulator is an air traffic control sim, I'll use that phraseology as an example:

Phrase A: on glide path

Phrase B: on course

Example: I say "on glide path on course". If the time between the two phrases doesn't have a large enough gap, it ignores the second phrase. When listening back to the last phrase, I only hear "on glide path on", so it seems that the recognizer takes a chunk of audio from the stream, processes it, then moves forward with the next audio chunk. But the problem is that it's clipped off audio for the next command.

I don't know what to do. Is it a speech engine problem, grammar file problem, or maybe something that can't be helped (since I'm doing continuous commands vs. continuous dictation)? Any pointers or help would be appreciated. Like I said, it works fine if I leave maybe a .5-1 second gap between commands, but air traffic controllers can be fast talkers, so I'm trying to figure out improvements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Speech Platform: recognize word repetitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879560/microsoft-speech-platform-recognize-word-repetitions)

Comment: You need to adjust the grammar

Comment: That looks like it is indeed the same problem. I'm going to go and try and see if it solves my problem. Thanks for pointing that out! Will check back soon.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I did a little research and got to thinking that the post you reference. Wouldn't that only pertain to the problem of repetitions in a command or phrase? (e.g. I like the colors <# of spoken words>)

Comment: there is no difference you can allow multiple commands in the grammar with same syntax.

Comment: If you put the repetition at the top of the grammar, then you can chain phrases together.